# How build a nonlinear approximation?

Tags: r, ggplot2

There was a need to build an approximation of data using the formula 
**y = a(exp(x/b) - 1)** (below the code).

```
library("ggplot2") 
df <- read.table(file='vah_p_1',header =TRUE)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x,  y = y)) + geom_point() +
geom_smooth(data = df, method = "nls",size=0.4, se=FALSE,color ='cyan2', 
formula = y ~ a(exp^(x*b)-1),method.args = list(start=c(a=1.0,b=0.0)))
p
```

Unfortunately the approximation line is not being built.I think the problem is in **method.args = list(start=c(a=1.0,b=0.0)**. How to find **a**, **b**?

In **vah_p_1** is located:

```
x       y
0       4
0.25    5
0.27    6
0,29    7
0.31    8
0.33    10
0.34    13
0.36    16
0.37    20
0.38    23
0.39    28
0.4     37
0.41    43
0.42    55
0.43    67
0.44    81
0.45    94
0.46    118
0.47    143
0.48    187
0.49    225
```

Comment: please include some part of data to make your problem reproducible

Comment: I've included data from vah_p_1 .

Comment: the problem is elsewhere, `geom_smooth()` should first work without any argument as it works for `ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()`

Comment: I inserted the command line `ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth() `. After the compilation got an error `geom_smooth()using method = 'loess' ` , although the chart was built.

Comment: Its not an error, just a note as it is mentioned in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241372/geom-smooth-using-method-loess-in-r)

Comment: finally figured out the problem, a typo, see the fourth value in the sample data you posted instead of `0.29` its `0,29`, when using `read.table` it is not converted to numeric. correct that and try again

Comment: Thank you everything is working. Now me need to build an approximation using  `geom_smooth(data = df, method = "nls",size=0.4, se=FALSE,color ='cyan2', 
formula = y ~ a(exp^(x*b)-1),method.args = list(start=c(a=1.0,b=0.0)))`, but after compilation I got an error  `Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
could not find function "a" `. Why not working? in this case **a = 1.0**

Comment: can you explain what you mean by `exp^(x*b)`?

Comment: I mistaken in   `y = a(exp^(x*b)-1)` . Correct `y = a*(exp(x*b) - 1)`, but after compilation I  get an error `Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates `.

Comment: In this case, I'm building a volt-ampere characteristic.

Comment: linearisation will probably help, refer to identical error at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160552/why-is-nls-giving-me-singular-gradient-matrix-at-initial-parameter-estimates

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved my problem